# Symfony 6: embedded form Collection with File upload in child form

Tags: symfony, file-upload, symfony6, formcollection

I have an entity `ClientFileAction` which is parent to an entity `Attachment` in `OneToMany` relation. `Attachment` holds not only file path, but also information about files, like title, upload date, etc.

`Attachment:`

```
#[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255)]
private $title;
#[ORM\Column(type: 'datetime')]
private $uploaded;
#[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255)]
private $filePath;
```

When it comes to create a form type `AttachmentType` and upload files **one to one**, there is no problem:

`AttachmentType:`

```
$builder
    ->add('title', null, ['label' => 'Title', 'required' => true])
    ->add('attachmentFile', FileType::class, [
        'label' => 'File',
        'mapped' => false,
        'required' => true,
        'constraints' => [
            new File([
                'maxSize' => '1024k',
            ])
        ],
    ]);
```

In the controller I just get uploaded file with `$attachmentFile = $form->get('attachmentFile')->getData();`  and then proceed to the usual `UploadedFile::move()` stuff.

**PROBLEM: EMBED AttachmentType IN PARENT FORM**

But when I try to upload multiple attachments (not only files, but attachments with a title field), the uploaded file field seems to be unreachable.

`ClientFileActionType:`

```
$builder
    ->add('description', null, ['label' => 'Description', 'required' => true])
    ->add('attachments', CollectionType::class, ['label' => false,
                                            'allow_add' => true,
                                            'by_reference' => false,
                                            'entry_type' => AttachmentType::class,
                                            'entry_options' => ['label' => false],
                                    ]);
```

When I embed the `AttachmentType` as *Collection* inside `ClientFileActionType`, then, in the controller I don't find a way to get uploaded files:

```
$attachments = $form->get('attachments')->getData();
```

`$attachments` is an array of `Attachment`, and, as `attachmentFile` is not a mapped field, it dissapeared on the `$form->handleRequest($request);`.

I need a way to get unmapped `attachmentFile` fields of the child forms someway, something like:

```
$attachmentFiles = $form->get('attachments.attachmentFile')->getData();
```

That throws an error. Is there a correct way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the correct way to do it as I was typing the question.

The uploaded files are in the `Request` object, so a correct approach for this scenario of file upload management could be:

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
{
    $i=0;
    $files = $request->files->all('client_file_action')['attachments'];

    foreach ($files as $file)
    {
        $attachmentFile = $file['attachmentFile'];

        $originalFilename = pathinfo($attachmentFile->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        
        $safeFilename = $slugger->slug($originalFilename);
        $newFilename = $safeFilename.'-' . uniqid() . '.' .$attachmentFile->guessExtension();

        $attachmentFile->move('path/to/folder',$newFilename);

        $attachment = $clientFileAction->findAttachment($i);

        if ($attachment != null)
            $attachment->setFilePath('path/to/folder/' . $newFilename);

        $i++;
    }
    $clientFileActionRepository->add($clientFileAction, true);
}
```